# Book where everyone but one man had genetic modification

Tags: story-identification, genetic-engineering, nanotechnology, transhuman

I remember, at some point, reading a book that I believe was a part of a short series.

It was about a time when nearly everyone had some level of genetic modification, and one man for some reason or other did not. At some point a sort of nanomachine that specifically dismantled the enhanced humans was released... I've missed a crap-ton of details between all those events, sorry I can't give better details...

Anything that you all think might be the one would help. I thought it might have been The Last Man because I remember the title being something not terribly different from that, but the description on Amazon doesn't match and the cover looks unfamiliar.

Thanks in advance for taking the time, even if nothing comes of it!

Comment: Please put some useful information in the title so it's not so generic.   Welcome to sff.SE.

Comment: Reminds me of the [melding plague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revelation_Space_universe)